# What's the significance of this wearable item on Hanna?

Tags: plot-explanation, props, midsommar

In *[Midsommar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8772262/)*, (2019) Hanna (played by Louise Peterhoff) appears to be wearing some kind of modern ankle strap/support. The item is black with red or orange trim and not in keeping with the rest of her white/pale pagan style costume.

[image: screen capture of the scene where the above-mentioned costume part is shown]

I don't recall it being mentioned or referenced, and it surely isn't there by mistake. So what is its significance, why is it there?

Comment: An image might be useful here.

Comment: I agree - I did look for an image.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've added a screen capture of a scene where I believe the costume part OP is talking about is shown. `@Mr_Thyroid, is this the correct costume part? If not, just rollback to a previous edit.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes that's the one - thanks for the screen grab.

Answer (score 2):

### There doesn't appear to be an intended significance for the audience to know

There's nothing in [the script](http://a24awards.com/film/midsommar/Midsommar_script.pdf) for that scene that draws attention to the 'brace'. The camera doesn't focus on it in close up, and no character makes reference to it.

> EXT. FIELD - DINING AREA - MINUTES LATER
>
> Siv gestures in the direction of a CARRIAGE, just beyond the tables. Its back sports TWO UNLIT TORCHES. Several girls (six to pull the carriage and six to accompany it) surround it. One GIRL scatters flowers to create a PATH between Dani and *the carriage. Dani RISES. Everyone else stands up, too.
>
> DANI
>   Can Christian come with me?
>
> SIV
>   No. The Queen must ride alone.
>
> Dani pauses to accept this. She steps onto the floral path and approaches the carriage. On the way, Hanna offers her a LONG, FLAMING STICK. Dani accepts it. Hanna motions to the carriage’s unlit torches. 
>   Dani walks to the carriage, extends the stick’s flame toward the torches, and sets them each AFIRE.
>
> Hanna takes the stick back from Dani, and gestures for her to enter the carriage. A TRADITIONALLY DRESSED MAN stands beside the carriage door. He hands Dani a VIAL OF HOLY SPRING WATER, and offers Dani his hand (for support) as she contemplates entering.

**It's presumably either part of her standard attire (which seems unlikely as it's only seen in the later scenes), decorative for the ceremony, or functional to support an injury.**

Additionally, we see other characters with orange touches to their white outfits, such as the headpiece of the Hargan men who light the torches:

[image: Hargan men]